# In iOS 10.3 and above, can alternate​Icon​Name be set and used for an image outside of an app bundle/binary?

Tags: ios

In iOS 10.3+, Apple has introduced the ability to change an app icon for an app, while running, from the default to any other image name that's been preloaded into the Info.plist:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname

Is it possible to set the image name to something like `generic.png`, build and load the app on a device, and then have my code create a `generic.png` file within my app's sandboxed document area to then use as my icon?

Or do all images used as icons need to be pre-built within the app bundle itself?

Comment: you need to add pre defined images with in your app, the other image name that's been preloaded into the Info.plist

Comment: Does Apple say that in their developer docs? Or do you know from experience? I am not near my Mac right now otherwise I'd just build a sample app to try for myself.

Answer (score 1):

The icons and info.plist are all part of your signed bundle, so you cannot modify them at run time.  Accordingly the icon image choices are limited to those that you ship with your app.